# Rails 4: ActionView::MissingTemplate even though view is defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, ruby-on-rails-4, sentry

I have a rails 4 application (social dating website) running in production with the following error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate

Missing template users/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:css], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder, :haml]}. Searched in: * "/app/app/views" * "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/kaminari-bootstrap-0.1.3/app/views" * "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/kaminari-0.14.1/app/views" * "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-dfc45d21fac4/app/views"
```

According to my sentry error reporting service, it's triggered when a user visits the following URL (https://www.example.com/users) and is referred by the URL      https://www.example.com/users/exampleuser

Yet when I login as other users visit those URLs manually, everything is fine.  Is it possible I'm out system resources to handle this request?  Or what could be causing this?

EDIT: All css on the page is being served out by the asset pipeline, so no css is hardcoded:

```
<link href="https://example-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/application-8b655bec4246e5fgbafe080f789b6f57.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<title>Some Site</title>
<link href="https://example-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/bootstrap_and_overrides-19bef7cd147t9f46ad2fg8908529a00e.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: there could be a typo?... what is the name of ur view folder for the user?

Comment: Gopal rathore: app/views/users/index.html.haml is the specific view file

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you've got a hard coded link to users.css that isn't handled by the asset pipeline. Your users#index action is trying to respond but of course you don't have a css.erb template so you get an error.

Comment: Thanks guys, still trying to run it down - no hardcoded css (see above EDIT).  The error has only happened twice, so it seems really obscure.  This error also occurred right around the time that I pushed a new deploy to heroku, so I wonder if somehow that had something to do with it.

Comment: I've had something similar. And nothing in the parameters of URI indicate that CSS is even wanted. Strange. This is on Rails 3.0.